# A super easy way to get several gold badges

Tags: discussion, badges, publicity

This is in response to this post: [How to increase traffic to the site?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10270/51970)

This site rewards publicity generously. If you share a link to a question, and the link is clicked on by 1000 different IP addresses, you get a gold badge. If you don't get a 1000, you still get a silver or a bronze.

You may say, "How does MSE know who posted the link?"  You don't copy the URL in the browser, you click the small "Share" button on the lower left of each question. This gives a URL uniquely identifying you as the sharer.

You have to share it with people who are interested, and not be a spammer.

Comment: Several people on other sites use Twitter.

Comment: And if the question you share is your own (which it does not have to be), you can get a `Popular Question` badge in addition. Sweet deal.

Comment: Is the last sentence technically true? Do you *have* to not be a spammer?

Comment: I *thought* I recognized one of those 15 questions... http://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/1hz56o/if_x_is_a_fraction_xx_and_xxx_are_irrational_but/

Comment: @julien Maybe the reason so few people have these badges is not that they are hard, but that awareness is low... which I think was the reason for Brian's PSA.

Comment: The difficult part is in establishing a website read by at least a thousand people. Super easy indeed! ;)

Comment: @40votes Indeed, the reason why the badges [Announcer](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/announcer) (bronze, 354 times), [Booster](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/60/booster)  (silver, 31) and [Publicist](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61/publicist) (gold, 15) are not awarded more often is probably due to the fact that not so many people are aware of it and how it works.

Comment: @ErikVesterlund Pfft, websites. Social networks is where it's at... leveraging your Klout score to obtain badges on StackExchange  is the new social media strategy. :)

Comment: I think few people have 1000 friends or followers on fb resp twitter, of which only a fraction would bother clicking a math related link ("math? i hated that shit in high school!")

Comment: @ErikVesterlund If I understood correctly, if you post a link somewhere on the web to a question using the address provided when you click on "share", it works too.

Comment: @RahulNarain reddit users always vote me down when I'm being spammy.

Comment: @40votes By googling reddit traffic I found that reddit is among the top 50 website in US, trailing only after NYT...So I am guessing posting on reddit may be a good idea to increase traffic and awareness? Also by following Chaz's link I do find there are some technical questions in math forum of reddit, maybe some users will find MSE a better place to ask questions after clicking the link?

Comment: @ShuhaoCao I doubt redditers would want to be proselytized... they are on `/r/math/` because they like reddit, not because it's the best place for math discussions. You may notice several references to MSE there... including [the infamous one](http://www.reddit.com/r/JusticePorn/comments/14q87t/student_cheats_on_math_homework_on_mathematics/), which led to [this otherwise unremarkable question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/256816/) getting over 18000 views, among some other things... Anyway, nothing against reddit, but I'm never going to post there.

Comment: @40votes wow, the forum's name is justiceporn...

Comment: @ShuhaoCao Yeah, a bit pretentious. I personally like   http://www.reddit.com/r/cheatatmathhomework/ - honest and clear statement.

Comment: @40votes Hopefully my students aren't doing their hw there...

Comment: If you want a gold badge why not get one you can wear by buying one on [EBay](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/gold-badge).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Here are other "super easy" ways:

1. Just check the site each day for a consecutive 100 days.
2. Ask a relatively simple question that shows that your children have mathematical genius written all over their faces.
3. Answer a relatively simple question which shows that the OP's children have mathematical genius written all over their faces, and be one of the first to do so. Preferably answer in simple words, either a very short and to the point answer, or a very very long and detailed answer.
4. Reach the required reputation, and just review 20 items a day of every available queue. Within 50 days you will have gold badges.
5. Learn to spot things which require flagging. Flag them on sight. Within a year you have a Marshal badge.
6. Become a moderator, and stick there for a year.
7. Go back in time and be a moderator during the beta stage of the site.
8. Become really good in writing good answers, and just hit the reputation cap every day. Wait 150 days.
9. Write 200 answers on a tag of your choice, so the average score on these answers is +5.
10. Hack into the SE servers and tamper with the database.
11. Find a really crappy question and answer it well. Then publish the link to the question without using your user identifier link.
12. Answer tons of obscure questions, becoming an Unsung Hero.
13. Teach a class which has over 100 attendants and tell them to use math.SE, then answer their questions online/ask questions related to the topic of the course and get their votes.
14. Vote all your votes, every day, for about 15 days.
15. Edit 500 posts.

There are probably more. And while all those ways are super easy some ways are more super easy than others.

Comment: My favorite is number 7, because it disproves Hawking's theories that we can only travel forward in time.

Comment: You omitted one of the easiest (but also important for the site) - **vote** 40 times a day for 15 days.

Comment: [Apparently Meta is the Wild Wild West](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/89/sheriff).

Comment: @40votes what is that? I don't see it listed on the Badges page. http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges

Comment: @40votes ah, do you mean electorate? There are some additional conditions involved...

Comment: @Willie: If there was more controversial activity, I'd probably sport a Deputy badge... :-P

Comment: @Willie The 25% condition is automatically fulfilled when someone votes 40 times a day, since 10 of those 40 votes are for questions only. Hence, the activity I described guarantees the badge.

Comment: ... assuming no prior voting activity, that is. If the user previously cast more than 75% of their votes on answers, they will find Electorate harder to get than new users. The only badge that holds your past against you... not very logical decision on SE part.

Comment: @40votes 600 **different questions**. So that someone will have to use up all 40 votes on **40 different questions** for 15 days to earn the badge. (Also, in your comment above you meant 75%+ on answers, not questions.)

Comment: @Willie Thanks, I misread. So, one can still get it in 15 days but this requires voting on questions only.

Comment: @40votes: There are more badges potentially "holding the past against you": Without cheating, Tenacious and especially Unsong Hero are only feasible in the beginning of your carreer, in my opinion. Deputy and Marshal get harder as you go up in reputation, since for example you cannot flag duplicates any more.

Comment: @azimut: Between my Marshal badge and the second Marshal badge given there was almost a full year in which I accumulated over 600 helpful flags, and moreover -- I had over 10k reputation at the time, so I had no duplicates to flag either. It's not hard, you just have to be slightly vigilant.

Comment: You omitted this "super(hero) easy" way: [the Batman gambit](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/54568/409).

Comment: @Blue: That's a close variant of no. 3, so I chose to omit that.

Comment: I wouldn't say 2 is "super easy" (granted that it is still easier that, say, 7): you still have to be the first - which is the most tricky part.

Comment: @Ilya Well, neither is posting a link and getting 1000 votes but that's the question so I think the answer fits.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: You noted the exact and the right points I have faced through the site. I am wonder, when I am aware of the level of Maths knowledge why should I try to get Gold B. In my interesting field, D.Holt is one of persons who is doing routinely answered the questions without any ambition. I have got this lesson from him to be standard as I am. Not as I  want to pretend. Thanks so much for noting these points one by one and Congs for being +100k. You really deserve it because you are Master in Maths. :-)

Comment: @Babak: Well, I did get my M.Sc. diploma a few weeks ago... ;-)

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way is surely making a post about Batman, it seems.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to get a Gold badge is to [Vote early, vote often](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/662/vote-early-vote-often). Vote on 600 questions and you will get yourself a Gold badge, the [Electorate Badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/electorate). This should take you 600/40=15 days. As a bonus you will get the [Civic Duty](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty) Silver badge (note: *duty*!). This is even easier to get: vote 300 times. It is interesting to note, though, that a mere 648 people have voted 300 or more times. Which is pathetic!

In conclusion, people don't vote enough. [Vote early, vote often](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/662/vote-early-vote-often)!

Comment: (This came up in the comments of Asaf's post, but I discovered the 648 figure today. Thought I should point it out...)

Comment: We should get [Ward](http://serverfault.com/users/6177/ward) interested in math... By the way, [the first page of voters list](http://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters&filter=all) still has Arturo Magidin and t.b... who are like mythical figures of Math.SE by now.

Answer (score 3):

There is a brand new   way to get a gold badge: asking **good** questions on $100$ separate days gets you a gold badge [Socratic](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/409/socratic).

There are bronze and silver badges of the same kind: [Curious](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/407/curious) and [Inquisitive](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/408/inquisitive).

Details are in the announcement: [Asking days badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259/).

Oh, and a **good** question does not have to be a [Good Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/21/good-question). I hope that's clear.

Comment: Now these are useful badges. Brb, adding most of badge holders to my [Stack User Filter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stack-user-filter/fehpncjhoepfablpiekjehnckbgkbipe).

Comment: What do they mean by "maintain a positive question record"?

Comment: @G.T.R It's... complicated. I added a link to the description.